# Indexing into a Dask Series gives back the Dask Series

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a Dask series of Dask dataframes.

I'd like to index into this series to acquire the dask dataframes for subsequent work.

However using `loc[0]` results in another dask series. Using `to_frame` also doesn't work because the result is then a "Dask dataframe of a Dask series of Dask dataframes".

Here is a minimal example that uses a Dask Series of Pandas dataframes (not exactly the same but illustrates the problem):

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

pdf1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [4,3,2,1]})
pdf2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4,3,2,1], 'b': [1,2,3,4]})

ps = pd.Series([pdf1, pdf2])
ds = dd.from_pandas(ps, npartitions=1)

print(type(ds.loc[0])) # still dask series
print(type(ds.loc[1])) # still dask series

print(ds.compute().loc[0]) # this is a pandas dataframe
print(ds.loc[0].compute()) # this is a pandas series
print(ds.loc[0].compute().loc[0]) # need to index into the singleton series to get back the dataframe
```

It appears that once the object becomes a dask series, all subsequent combinators keeps it as a dask series until `compute`, which returns a "singleton" pandas series.

Is there anyway to tell dask to treat the indexed object the type that I expect it to be?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the reason for this is that Dask does not know that there is only one index value with the value 0.  In principle there could be many rows with the index value 0, and so the general output type for `.loc` is a series.

This goes against our intuition when we have uniquely valued indices, which can cause the kind of frustration that you seem to have encountered.

Comment: So there's no solution for this atm? I find that the only way to deal with these cases is to convert to delayed and work on that directly and then convert back to whatever is needed.

Comment: The solution is that we always return a series.  From a Dask perspective this is not a bug, but rather an odd type inconsistency on the Pandas side.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a reasons for keeping your dataframes in a series that I do not understand from the example, but my guess is that you would be better served by keeping your original dataframes as partitions in dask. You can then join them using the `concat`, as in the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

pdf1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [4,3,2,1]})
pdf2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4,3,2,1], 'b': [1,2,3,4]})

ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(pdf1, npartitions=1)
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(pdf2, npartitions=1)

ddf = dd.concat([ddf1, ddf2], axis=0)
ddf.compute()
```

You can access the first partition with with `ddf.partitions[0].compute()`

More importantly, if you original dataframes are indexed and the index sorted and the indexes are not overlapping, then `concat` will correctly set the divisions of the joined dataframes, without needing to reindex. You can check divisions with `ddf.divisions`, which will show `(None, None, None)` in this example, but correct divisions if you start out with proper indexing.